# Cannot click a link on automation testing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I had coded automation testing for company website but there is some link is not clickable. Error is

> [ERROR]   GenericTestManager.testPDPA:589 Element should be clickable:
> interactable and enabled {By.xpath: (//a[@href='/privasi'])[1]}
> Element: ''
> Actual value: hidden, opacity=1

My code is

```
@Test
    public void testPDPA() {
        extentTest = extentManager.getExtentReports().createTest("PDPA Test");

        $x("(//a[@href='/privasi'])[1]").click();
}
```

Is there anything i can make it clickable or visible? Thanks.

Comment: Is it the GUI element hidden, so called opacity?

Comment: why not just write up the bug??  It's hard to say without looking at this assert, what/why it is throwing here... the xpath you are using is a little odd though.  Why the "[1]"?

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: If you can, add a link to that website

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, without knowledge of your DOM structure, I can suggest you to perform click via native JS.

```java
Selenide.executeJavaScript("arguments[0].click()", $x("(//a[@href='/privasi'])[1]"));
```

Selenide emulates real user behaviour, so it contains checks that element is not hidden. Easier workaround is to click via JS.
Hidden element is not interactable - it doesn't have size and location. So technically as a user, you can't click on it.

I created an HTML structure for you, where you can test behaviour. In this structure button is hidden by default and become visible only on click.

This code would fail:

```java
        Selenide.open("https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-08-30.html");
        $("#hiddenButton").should(exist).click();
```

This code would click without problems (button would become visible)

```java
        Selenide.open("https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-08-30.html");
        Selenide.executeJavaScript("arguments[0].click()", $("#hiddenButton"));
```

Comment: Is it the GUI element hidden or transparency?

Comment: @nicholas I edit detailed explanation with example in my answer, try it.